# How to invoke a service after pressing submit in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I am very new to Drupal and I am asked to create form with a submit button and a service that makes a get request to an API with the values from the form. The API is a simple API that the user can enter a country and it will return a response with the correct greeting from that country.

This is my routing file:

```
hello_world.salutation:
  path: '/hello'
  defaults:
    _controller: Drupal\hello_world\Controller\HelloWorldSalutation::salutation
    _form: Drupal\hello_world\Form\GreetingForm
    _title: 'Get a greeting from a different language'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer site configuration'
```

First problem is that I do not know how to make the form and the controller in the same routing,
and second is that I do not know how to invoke that service when the user has entered submit.

Here is my services file:

```
services:
  hello_world.salutation:
    class: Drupal\hello_world\HelloWorldSalutation
    arguments: [ '@config.factory' ,'@tempstore.private']
  cache.nameofbin:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface
    tags:
      - { name: cache.bin }
    factory: [ '@cache_factory', 'get' ]
    arguments: [ nameofbin ]
```

I will skip some lines from the GreetingFrom class to keep it simple, but I can add them if it is required.

Here is the submitForm function from the GreetingForm class. The idea is to put the input in a global tempstore so I cal access the values from the controller I guess.

```php
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    $search_str = $form_state->getValue('greeting');
    // check the input
    $params['items'] = $form_state->getValue('greeting');
    // 2. Create a PrivateTempStore object with the collection 'greetingForm_values'.
    $tempstore = $this->tempStoreFactory->get('greetingForm_values');
    // 3. Store the $params array with the key 'params'.
    try {
      $tempstore->set('params', $params);
    } catch (\Exception $error) {
      // dump the error for now, read error, --fix this!
      dpm($error);
    }
  }
```

And the salutation function from the controller looks like this:

```php
  public function salutation()
  {
    $tempstore = $this->tempStoreFactory->get('greetingForm_values');
    $params = $tempstore->get('params'); // this value should come from the search form
    return [
      '#markup' => $this->salutation->getGreeting($params),
    ];
  }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, and please ask for more information if it is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Routing file

In your use case I believe you can stick to the use of a Form. Please discard the Controller specification from your `hello_world.salutation` route, because it should be either `_form` or `_controller`, not both for a single route.

### Service method invocation

For your service definition, you can do this by either statically calling the service as:

```
$salutation_service = \Drupal::service('hello_world.salutation');
$salutation_service->somePublicMethodCall();
```

or via Dependency Injection which I assume you are already doing when I look at `this->salutation->getGreeting($params)`?

### Form x Controller

From the provided details, I can't really tell why you need the Controller, but if you need to redirect to the Controller, then you could create a separate route for your `HelloWorldSalutation::salutation()` method and redirect to it from `GreetingForm ::submitForm()` via the `$form_state` object:

```
$url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('hello_world.salutation');
$form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
```